Will I get shocked touching the hot wire in these cases?
I have 2 questions in the situation if I stupidly touch the hot wire in a circuit:

If the neutral wire is not grounded, then if I touch the hot wire, there is not return path from the hot wire, through my body, to the generator. In this case, will I be shocked ?

If the neutral wire is grounded, then if I touch the hot wire, there is indeed a closed circuit from hot wire, through my body, through earth, to the grounding wire of the neutral, and to the generator.
However, as I understand, the current will always choose the least resistent path to go back to the source. In this case, it is the path through the neutral wire and not through my body (because my body, and earth has much much higher resistence than the neutral wire). In this case, I shouldn't get shocked, right ? Is there any flawness in my reasoning ?


Edited: below image to illustrate the case 2, where you should understand that Rover touches the hot wire, and there is already a returning path (hot wire -> load -> neutral wire -> source), so there are 2 returning paths if Rovers touches the hot wire.

Many thanks for your help with these questions!

Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/594326/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/605299/226902

Never ever touch a hot wire. It's stupid.

3-phase to homes is rare to non-existent.

This might help - Where Does Grounded Electricity Actually Go?

"Electricity takes the path of least resistance" is the worst quasi-truth in all of electrical design.  It does take the path of least resistance -- it takes all paths, of which the path of least resistance is just one of them.  I wish we didn't teach it.

Case 1: neutral is not grounded.
Touching the hot wire causes a load (human body) to be connected from hot to earth.  Since there is no connection to earth of the electrical supply, then in theory the human body "drags" the voltage of the touched active toward earth, causing the voltage at the neutral point of supply to go to a high voltage.  In practice, however, the electrical installation will have significant "parasitic capacitance" from neutral to earth, meaning that some current must flow through the human body to cause the neutral voltage to rise above earth potential to where it needs to be to allow the voltage of the touched active to go to zero.  This current will depend on the electrical installation, and the loads connected to it; many electronic loads have capacitors connected from neutral to earth, and active to earth, as part of internal EMC filters.
So in case 1, you will still receive some electrical current, and whether that is harmful or even lethal depends on (a) how much current flows, (b) the duration of the current, and (c) the sensitivity of the individual to that current.
Just to put some numbers on this matter: if the amplitude of the current remains below, say, 1 micro-amp and lasts mere few micro-seconds, then it is very unlikely to cause the victim any permanent damage.  However, if the current is above, say,  50mA and lasts for several seconds, then it is very likely to cause some harm (or possibly death), the degree of harm will depend on the health, fitness, and physiological constitution of the human victim.
The amplitude of the current that flows through the human victim will depend on the exact circumstances at the time, some of which are listed below:

the local weather, and in particular humidity and dampness of the surfaces,
clothes and footwear,
how effectively the human body is making electrical contact at both (a) the active conductor and (b) the earth,
the type of skin the person has, and whether that skin is wet or has any cuts,
the amount of parasitic capacitance between the earth and the active conductor.

It is complicated to predict with any precision how much current will flow through a person that is exposed to a given voltage, since it depends on so many variables.  Here is a quote from a respected authority that may illustrate how complex and nuanced this is.

The body has resistance to current flow. More than 99% of the body's resistance to electric current flow is at the skin. Resistance is measured in ohms. A calloused, dry hand may have more than 100,000 Ω because of a thick outer layer of dead cells in the stratum corneum. The internal body resistance is about 300 Ω, being related to the wet, relatively salty tissues beneath the skin. The skin resistance can be effectively bypassed if there is skin breakdown from high voltage, a cut, a deep abrasion, or immersion in water (Table ​(Table2).2).

Reference:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2763825/
Also consider that the effect of the same current may be completely different for different individuals; what one healthy person may pass off as a "mild buzz" may be lethal for someone in a weakened state or dependent upon medical devices (such as a pace-maker).
Case 2: neutral is grounded.
Now the human body is connected across the active and earth, and the neutral is connected to earth by a good conductor, the earth wire.  What you didn't show on your diagram is the connection between neutral and earth at the house switchboard, which is in addition to the neutral to earth connection at the electrical company transformer.  This means that the resistance between your feet and neutral is quite low, meaning you now have a good electrical connection across the full active to neutral voltage of the electrical supply.
So, in case 2, you will receive a very serious, possibly lethal, electrical shock.

Hi, thanks for your comment. Could you explain me why in the 1st paragraph, you wrote "causing the voltage at the neutral point of supply to go to a high voltage", i mean what is the relationship between the touched point and the "neutral point of supply" ? could you please confirm me what do you mean by saying "neutral point of supply" ? do you mean the point of the neutral wire which is located at the distributor (before each household's electric system) ? Many thanks!

Q1. "what is the relationship between the touched point and the "neutral point of supply" ?   Answer: For case 1, the votlage of the touched point becomes the same as earth voltage, assuming there is no other electrical path from active to ground.  If the active becomes earth votlage. then the neutral must become high voltage wrt earth.  Active and neutral are the two nodes of a defined voltage source; whether one or the other is at the same voltage as earth depends on the electrical installation.

Q2. could you please confirm me what do you mean by saying "neutral point of supply" ? do you mean the point of the neutral wire which is located at the distributor (before each household's electric system) ?  Answer: Yes, it is the neutral point at the suppliers transformer.  This point connects to the wire marked "neutral" on your drawing.

I have updated my answer to warn you that even in Case 1 there is a very real risk of electrical shock.  Please do not touch electrical wires unless you are properly trained and authorised to do so.  Even if you do not put your health or life in danger, you may endager the lives of others.

Hi, in fact in the case 1, i don't really understand why should the voltage of touched point equal to voltage of earth ? given that human body can be seen as a resistor. As for me, voltage of touched point is equal to earth IF it is connected to earth by the earthing wire with very very low resistence, which isn't the case here. It is like in a normal circuit, the voltage between 2 ends of a resistor isn't equal. Can you explain me what you think abt it ?

The human body is a very low resistance when compared to infinite resistance.   In a floating system where each node (active, neutral) has a resistance to earth that is infinite, then connecting any node to earth via a resistance of, say, 10kΩ, is almost the same as connecting it via a conductor.    I have updated my answer.

Hi, thanks for your help so far. Forgive me but I still don't get it why in case 1, there can be some current from the neutral wire through the body to earth, meanwhile I don't touch the neutral wire (I touch the hot wire). Maybe ultimately you mean that there is some "temporary" current from the hot wire through my body to earth in a very short time to equalize the potential difference between the hot wire and earth, and there is nothing to do with the neutral wire ??

Yes, there will be the "temporary current" you mentioned.   But in addition, there will be "continuous current", the amount of this will be dependant on many practical factors.  In an ideal system where there is infinite resistance (zero conductivity) between earth and all parts of the electrical system, then yes, no current will flow.  The danger is, however, that no system is ideal, and there will always be some current path between earth and many parts of the electrical system.

Maybe i'm stupid but I still don't get it. You mean there can be a continuous current from neutral wire through my body to earth meanwhile there is no direct touch of the neutral wire ? the current flows through air ?? @@

Your body will then complete the circuit.  The circuit that causes current to flow through your body is: the active of the voltage source in the electrical system, the active conductor, you, the earth, then the non-zero conductivity from the earth to the neutral of the electrical system.

Yes, some of that "non-zero conductivity from the earth to the neutral" is indeed air - that is what a capacitor is, two conductors that are not touching each other separated by an insulator, such as air.  Does AC current pass through a capacitor?  Yes, yes indeed it does.  Basic AC theory will tell you that.

In the previous comment, you mentionned "then the non-zero conductivity from the earth to the neutral of the electrical system", but as the neutral is not grounded, how can there be this non-zero conductivity please ?

Do you understand the following: 1. What a capacitor is.  2. Basic AC circuit theory.

If you do not understand what a capacitor is, OR you do not understand that a current will flow through a capacitor when the current is AC, then I suggest you ask those questions and do some basic research on these topics.  ||  And I suggest you do take the time to understand these concepts before doing anything silly like trying to prove your theory by touching the active, or in fact touching any part of any electrical system.  From our discussion, it is clear that you have no experience in any of this, and tinkering with this could be very dangerous for you, or for others.  Cheers.

What confuses me is that you said "some of that "non-zero conductivity from the earth to the neutral" is indeed air" which means that there is other non-air conductivity from the earth to neutral, which doesn't exist for me because I don't touch the neutral wire (and it isn't grounded). So for me, all conductivity is air...

There is also the insulation materials.   The insulation that coats the neutral wire is not perfect.  It leaks current.  It touches the earth, and it touches the natural wire.  Thus it
also helps form the "non-zero conductivity from the earth to the neutral".   Not just the wire has this problem - every electrical item in the installation that uses insulation material (such as plastics) has this problem.  No insulator is perfect.

Also, as I have already mentioned, the neutral and the active are both connected to the earth via actual real capacitors:  many electronic loads have capacitors connected from neutral to earth, and active to earth, as part of internal EMC filters.



...
However, as I understand, the current will always choose the least
resistant path to go back to the source. In this case, it is the path
through the neutral wire and not through my body (because my body, and
earth has much much higher resistance than the neutral wire). In this
case, I shouldn't get shocked, right ? Is there any flaw in my
reasoning ?


The flaw is you are assuming it is a case of either/or when it fact it is both. Consider two resistors in parallel in a DC circuit. If the two resistors have have different resistances, the current does not just go through the resistor with least resistance but goes through both proportionally to the relative resistances. The current through R1 is equal to V/R1 and the current through R2 is V/R2, where the voltage across each resistor is necessarily the same. Unless one the two resistors has zero resistance they both have a current passing through them.
If the voltage is very high and you touch the wire, there will be a brief pulse going through you, as you touch the hot wire due to the finite time it takes for your voltage to equalise with the wire voltage. If the voltage is both high and alternating very rapidly the voltage difference never truly equalises and there is continuous alternating current flowing through you. Check out the visible arc between this helicopter HV line inspector and the line as he approaches the HV line at around time stamp 3.35 in this video. The line inspector is protected by a special conducting suit that forms a Faraday cage and routes the  current around his body. Note that the helicopter is not grounded and there is only the small resistance of the air between the helicopter and the ground, and yet a significant current can be seen passing between the line and the helicopter.
It is never safe to assume it safe to work on a live high voltage circuit unless you really know what you are doing and take necessary precautions.

in the first paragraph, you said that there might be a current through
me, but as the neutral isn't grounded, there is no closed loop from
hot wire, through my body back to source, how could there be a current
flows through my body ? Can you please explain me - InTheSearchForKnowledge

In the light of your comment, I have done a deeper dive and revised my answer. You are correct that there is no closed loop, but that does not mean no current flows at all. There is a certain amount of inductance and capacitance in the cables, the coils of the generator and the human body itself and there is small residual alternating current due continuously alternating voltage transferring energy back and forth because capacitors and inductors alternately store and discharge energy. This residual current is probably only of the order of milliamps and unlikely to be dangerous, but there might be a small risk if directed through your heart. The currents seen passing from the overhead cables to the helicopter or sometimes seen where broken cables arc to ground are due to much higher voltages/capacitance and inductance than are found in a domestic power supply. In fact, not having the neutral connected to earth at the generator end, makes the system less dangerous from the point of view of getting a lethal shock. The real reason domestic equipment is earthed, is to prevent lightening strikes causing arcing and fires in your domestic electrical equipment. See this video for why an earthed neutral can put you at risk of getting a more severe shock.
In a normal domestic (two phase) power supply with an earthed neutral, the shock protection is provided by a residual current device (RCD). If a leak  occurs to earth (perhaps through you) the RCD detects a difference between the current returning on the neutral line compared to the live line and breaks the circuit. Normally, if a hot wire comes into contact with a metal case of a piece of earthed equipment, the flow of current to earth via the metal case will cause the RCD to break the circuit, hopefully before anyone comes into contact with the equipment. Earthing the equipment locally, when the neutral is also earthed at the power source, allows the RCD device to be more effective.

Hello, in the first paragraph, you said that there might be a current through me, but as the neutral isn't grounded, there is no closed loop from hot wire, through my body back to source, how could there be a current flows through my body ? Can you please explain me ?

@InTheSearchForKnowledge See my revised answer.

Case 1 has no conducting path (only a bit of capacitive current might flow if it is AC, so you might at most feel a small tingling). Case 2) in your description has only one path, through your body, so you will get shocked. It is not clear which other path you are referring to!

In case 2, i think that the other return path is through the neutral wire, so there are 2 returning paths indeed.., right ?

You should draw it.

I have edited my question, can you have a look at it ?

You didn't draw anyone touching the hot wire. And you didn't draw any path (from the hot wire back to the hot wire. Let alone two different paths, so the question is still not explained, as before...)

The reason the neutral is grounded is that there is generally significant leakage of current from primary to secondary of the utility's step-down transformer, driven by the high primary voltage. Grounding the neutral returns that leakage to the utility through the ground, bypassing more dangerous paths through Rover or you.
